# What is increment/decrement address latch in 8085

Tags: register, 8085

Can you please explain about increment/decrement latch in 8085. I am currently studying registers and encountered this in the array of register section.

**Here are the things i found when i googled and need some explanations**

> The 8-bit contents of a register or a memory location can be
>   incremented or decremented by 1.
>
> This 16-bit register is used to increment or decrement the content of
>   program counter and stack pointer register by 1.
>
> Increment or decrement can be performed on any register or a memory
>   location.

Q1.How are the above mentioned operations done by it please explain that.

**Also Please explain this:**

[image]

Q2. The term Address Latch in the above context is also confusing me so it be great relief i someone explains that to me.

Q3. In the block diagram increment/decrement latch is connected to the address and data buffer why is it so?

Thanks!

Comment: There's really no way to answer this unless you give us some idea of what you already understand about computers in general, and about the 8085 specifically.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I know fair amount of digital electronics and i am starting to learn microprocessor and encountered this while learning registers

Comment: Where did you find this excerpt?

Comment: @Dave - Hi, in case it helps, I found the OP's quoted text inserted as an image in the question, in [this pdf](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/108107029/module4/lecture15.pdf) - which appears to be part of the course materials from an online course from "NPTEL" in India called "[Introduction of Microcomputer, Microcontrollers (...)](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/108107029/)".

Comment: @SamGibson: I suspected as much. Thanks for putting a lot more effort into this than I ever would have!

Comment: @SamGibson is right i am taking the same course

Answer (score 1):

That last sentence (*"An increment/decrement register ..."*) is indeed confusing.

First of all, it should have started a new paragraph, because it really has nothing to do with the rest of the paragraph to which it is attached.

Second, increment/decrement is a function block, not a register. You can feed the contents of any of the 16-bit register pairs through this logic in order to modify the value.

---

Regarding the rest of the paragraph, as it says, the address latch is an internal implementation detail, used to hold an address from any of the 16-bit registers in order to maintain bus timing while other internal operations are going on. It is not a user-accessible architectural feature.